# Getting exception while running textcase with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). How to fix this issue?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-boot-test

> Exception in thread "I/O dispatcher 1" java.lang.AssertionError   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.Response.assertWarningValue(Response.java:193)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.Response.extractWarningValueFromWarningHeader(Response.java:183)
>     at org.elasticsearch.client.Response.getWarnings(Response.java:205)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:546)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:537)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: What is the question? I don't see a question mark

Comment: Question is how to resolve this Exception which i am facing while running test case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information here but let me try to answer.
I had the same error you had when I was using spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2 and elasticsearch version 7. Every request to ES DB works using that combination but it also logs a warning message `[types removal] Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated...`

If this is really your case, try to update spring-data-elasticsearch to version 4.0.1 and you'll be fine.